# jquery - select parent by child attribute without use of parent()

Tags: jquery

Is there a selector that can returns the parent by child attribute without the use of `parent()`

ex:

```
$('th[role="columnheader"] > .k-link');
```

this function above returns the children with `class="k-link"` which parent is a `th` and have the attribute `role="columnheader"`.

Is there a way to select the parent directly?

I want to get the parent not the children, but I dont want to do

```
$('th[role="columnheader"] > .k-link').parent();
```

Edit: reason of this: the selector string will be passed dynamically and sometimes the parent will be needed and sometimes not. I cant access the parent directly by class or id because those I want are just differenced by their children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) Selector

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector

```
$('th[role="columnheader"]:has(> .k-link)');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$('th[role="columnheader"]:has(".k-link")');
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/9gnhopnm/)